# How do I find the least number of employees in a supermarket?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, optimization

The problem is as follows:

> 7-11 (Seven-eleven) has numerous branches across Taipei. The newest
> manager knows that in $k$ stores where a total of $10k$ employees
> work. The latest report also indicates that in none of those stores
> works less than $k+2$ neither more than $3(k+1)$ employees. If the
> greatest number of employees in four stores is $43$. Find the value of
> $k$.

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{6 employees}\\
2.&\textrm{5 employees}\\
3.&\textrm{7 employees}\\
4.&\textrm{9 employees}\\
\end{array}$

What sort of logic is used to solve this problem?. What I attempted so far was doing this:

$k+2<k(10k)<3(k+1)$

From this I'm getting:

$k+2<10k^2<3k+3$

I don't know if the intended meaning of this problem is that those less than or greater than consider the boundaries, in other words to be $\leq$ or $\geq$.

Does it exist any word in the problem which specify that any of these conclusions should be considered?. I don't know **when to use $\leq$ or $\geq$**.

More over what to do next?. My book states that the answer is $7$, but I don't know how to get there.

Can someone help me with a step by step solution?.

Comment: Why did you multiply 10 k by k, instead of multiplying k+2  or 3(k+1) by k?

Comment: While $k = 7$ would do it, so would $k = 6$. So giving both as alternatives to choose does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

$k$ denotes the number of stores. 
$10k$ employees work in these stores, so the average number of employees in each store is 10.

Therefore $~(k + 2) ~\leq ~10 ~\leq ~3(k+1).$ 
Therefore $~k ~\leq ~8 ~~\text{and} ~~k \geq 3.$

Further, $~10 k ~\geq ~43 ~\implies ~k ~\geq ~5.$

Examine each of these cases individually:

$\underline{\text{Case 1:} ~k = 5}$ 
Minimum in each store is 7 and maximum is 18.
50 total employees in all stores combined. 
At least one group of 4 stores has 43 employees. 
No group of 4 stores has more than 43 employees.

$\{7, 10, 11, 11, 11\}~$ works.

$\underline{\text{Case 2:} ~k = 6}$ 
Minimum in each store is 8 and maximum is 21.
60 total employees in all stores combined. 
At least one group of 4 stores has 43 employees. 
No group of 4 stores has more than 43 employees.

$\{8, 9, 10, 11, 11, 11\}~$ works.

$\underline{\text{Case 3:} ~k = 7}$ 
Minimum in each store is 9 and maximum is 24.
70 total employees in all stores combined. 
At least one group of 4 stores has 43 employees. 
No group of 4 stores has more than 43 employees.

$\{9, 9, 9, 10, 11, 11, 11\}~$ works.

$\underline{\text{Case 4:} ~k = 8}$ 
Minimum in each store is 10 and maximum is 27.
80 total employees in all stores combined. 
At least one group of 4 stores has 43 employees. 
No group of 4 stores has more than 43 employees.

This won't work because:
If one group of 4 stores has 43 employees, the total number of
employees in the other 4 stores must be 37.  This contradicts the requirement that the minimum that work in each store is 10.

---

Therefore, you have 3 possible values of $k$ that will satisfy the requirements.  This is the point where I would **meta-cheat**.  The way that the problem is worded, and the way that the choices are given, as a mathSE reviewer, the status of the problem at this point is unacceptable.  Therefore, I have only two choices:

- Request that I would *like to buy a vowel*.
- Attempt telepathy.

Forgoing buying a vowel, look at the title of the query:

> How do I find the least number of employees in a supermarket?

My *telepathy* suggests that you are supposed to identify all possible satisfying values of $k$, and then choose the minimum.
Based on this:

Final answer:

$$k = 5.$$